# Adjust a horizontal recyclerview so the last visible item is partially visible?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am thinking of **adjusting the width** of each item a bit dynamically **depending on screen size** and **number of items**, but i am not able to find an easy solution to test it on different screen sizes. Is there an easier way?

Comment: You could adjust width of each item in recyclerview as a percentage of phone screen width instead of some fixed amount, that way it should look the same on different screen sizes and it shouldn't be so painful to implement and test.

Comment: Interesting. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Language improved